# Installing Virtual box for kong Vagrant set up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I am trying to set up vagrant for kong. I have installed VirtualBox and vagrant. But when i run 'vgrant up' i encounter the below issue:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["list", "hostonlyifs"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154) - Class not registered (extended info not available)
```

I have searched for this error with no much luck.

I am using centos 7.4 and the kernel version is 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64.

I have downloaded the relevant gcc, devel and dkms. In short followed the link https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-virtualbox-on-centos-redhat-and-fedora/

Any tip is appreciated.

Thanks
Dinah

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with your VirtualBox install, not Vagrant. To confirm this, you should receive the same error when running: `VBoxManage list vms`

A common reason for this error are when `/tmp` is full or has the incorrect permissions.

To check if `/tmp` is full try `df -h`

To fix permissions on `/tmp` if they're incorrect, try `sudo chmod ug-s /tmp && sudo rm -rf /tmp/.vbox*`

Comment: I tried this one too yet I get the same issue. I agree this is the issue with VirtualBox install but unfortunately, the resolutions mentioned are not helping.

Comment: It would be of great help if there are other alternatives, or if there is something else that I might be probably be missing on

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we were trying this on a VM. And Vagrant tries to spin up another VM. So having a VM spun within a VM is causing the issue.